# How to draw a translucent rectangle on a static text?

Tags: python, text, wxpython, draw

I draw a tranlucent rectangle on my panel but on the places that have static text's the rectangle is not filled.

I've drawn rectangles inside each static text but when I do that, the correspondent text doesn't happear.

How can I draw a translucent rectangle inside the statix text without making the text disappear?

The code is like this:

```
dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
gc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255,  255,  0, 22))) # Translucid Yellow
gc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, self.GetClientSizeTuple()[0], self.GetClientSizeTuple()[1])
```

My static text is allready tranparent but still doesn't happear the translucent rectangle on it! How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "translucid rectangle".  Could you please clarify, if possible?  Do you mean translucent?

Maybe you could try drawing the rectangles **under** the static text, instead of over them?

Comment: when I draw under (on the panel), I the draw the control over and its background takes control

Comment: Could you post a minimal but complete working example.  Also, can you just write text directly to the GC or do you really need static text?  Finally, what OS are you on (awhile back, and maybe now too, StaticText had issues with transparent background on Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associate the onPaint event to all statix text's.